# Select the minimum column in a specific row (R)

Tags: r

I have some issue with R. I try to extract the column with the minimum value in each row. Let me explain :

```
Test = data.frame(Day1 = c(1,6,3,8), Day2 = c(2,5,4,9)
```

Output:

```
    Day1 Day2
1    1    2
2    6    5
3    3    4
4    8    9
```

I want to create a 3rd column which select the minimum value of each column (so for row 1, it would be 1 (Day1) ; row 2, it would be 5 (Day2) ; row 3, it would be 3 (Day1), etc...

Thanks if anyone has a tip !

EDIT: found it, but I don't know now how can I create a 4th column with the name of the minimum ? (for row 1, it would be Day1 ; row 2 it would be Day2, etc...) ?

Comment: It works ! Thanks. And do you know how can I create a 4th column with the name of the minimum ? (for row 1, it would be Day1 ; row 2 it would be Day2, etc...) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` the following to find the minimum value in each row.

```
Test$minimum <- apply(Test,1,which.min)
```

Setting a parameter of `1` runs the code `which.min` over each row of `Test`.

To get the column name of the minmum column, add `colnames(Test)` before `apply`

```
Test$minimum_day <- colnames(Test)[apply(Test,1,which.min)]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it works ! But I don't know now how can I create a 4th column with the name of the minimum ? (for row 1, it would be Day1 ; row 2 it would be Day2, etc...) ?
I've tried test$daymin <- apply(Test,1,colnames(which.min)), but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I just edited my comment above. You were close, but had to move `colnames` outside of the apply function.